# Set particle emission number

Tags: particles, animation-nodes

[image: How]

I have a empty with a cube shape. Inside that I generate points. Then I have a torus, if a point is inside the torus then I render it as a particle, if it is outside the torus then I ignore it.

[image]

At the moment I need to set the exact amount of partciles in the `Emission > Number`.

[image]

If I do too few, I don't get a full shape. If I do too many, then I get an exception (only if I use rotations as well). This seems like a bug to me, which I will report in a second.

Anyway, is there any way to set the particle number from within animation nodes?

Comment: This is not a bug, the current Blender-particle system does not allow to change particle-number during the simulation. You can set the number of particles with animation nodes But the problem is it rests the particle cache. Can you tell what kind of effect you want to achieve?

Comment: Im making a model to voxels thing. Where each voxel is a particle. I continue on your github for the reply.